# How to build web client/system tests on an App Engine project?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, testing, django-nonrel

Is there a common/best practice way to build a client-side javascript test platform for GAE python?

I know the GAE SDK has a Testbed API, and there's nose-gae.  Both of these seem to be designed for unit-testing of server side code.  I'm currently running on django-nonrel, and using django's unit test framework for this.

I'm looking for a similar testing framework where I can load fixture data, but run a real HTTP server so I can run Selenium tests against the server.  This way I can test my javascript AJAX calls against fixed data.

I'm currrently achieving this by having django's test framework launch the GAE SDK dev_appserver on a separate thread after loading fixtures.  This is able to handle HTTP calls from a browser.  It mostly works for me, but there's a few cases where there's some flaky threading issues.  The worst part is that it's rather hacky and calls deep into the SDK to launch dev_appserver.  This is going to break with dev_appserver2.

I'm wondering if there's a better way to solve this.  With all the GAE devs out there, someone else must be running system tests against fixed data?